# Suggestions regarding Algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, advice

I have recently completed my undergraduate degree. Now, I have started reading Algebraic topology Hatcher's book. I have read chapter 0 & 1 . But I am not able to solve excercise.How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: great question with no good answer. Try reading other books, Hatcher leaves much to be desired (arguably) (but is also great at the same time...); having more sources to draw from will at any rate give you more examples and more insight

Comment: It sounds to me like you are trying to read a book that is too advanced for your level.  I recommend finding an easier book where you can solve the exercises.  Reading that will give you more experience and prepare you for reading Hatcher.

Comment: Any suggestions for books?

Comment: Possibly useful are the comments and answer to [Hatcher Algebraic Topology: I have all the prereqs, so why is this book unreadable for me?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3492949/13130)

Comment: Did you check out the end of Munkres with the fundamental group stuff? IMO CW complexes don't really matter that much until homology.